# Fig tree languishing after 2 years - how to reinvigorate?

Tags: soil, growth, figs

I have a fig tree which was planted two years ago next to a wall.  The soil-side of the wall faces north, the sunny pavement side face south, so it provides plenty of heat.  The sun can shine on the tree itself too.  So I don't think light is an issue.

How can I best improve the soil?  Perhaps moisture retention is an issue too?

[image: Fig]

[image: fig 2]

Comment: Can  yuu add a photo of the plant and its situation please

Comment: Is it next to a wall with a foundation? Where there's concrete, you can have problems with alkaline soil.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've added some pictures now.  As you can see the street is near and the wall might well have concrete foundations.  As it happens I already have a pH tester, never used until now, so I'll try it out and post the results.  As you can see, the wall would blot out quite a bit of light on the stem, but I believe enough light still reaches it.

Comment: It looks like the fig has quite a bit of competition, too. I would have expected that to be MUCH larger after 2 years.

Comment: @That Idiot, that's true, for some reason I'd assumed a fig would out-compete a rubbishy fuschia, what with it being a tree.  In my mind a fig is pretty vigorous and fairly quick to grow.  It seems I've over-estimated it's strength, it is a sapling after all, I'll see how the fuschia and it's friends fare in a battle vs the fork!